# Why doesn't mac laptop screen/logo stay off with `xset`? (ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: 20.04, macbook-pro

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 on a 2013 MacBook Pro.

I configured the lid to stop going to sleep on close.

If I issue this command with the lid closed:

```
xset -display :0.0 dpms force off
```

The screen goes off and the logo goes dark, and then the logo comes back on again 1-2 seconds later.

(I actually issue this in a script when the ACPI lid event fires, but I'm trying to debug why it doesn't work first.)